# Grouping of Event Time Data based on multiple, iterative conditions

Tags: r, grouping, detection, temporal

I have a dataset of ~190,000 rows which includes:
Sample Data: [found here:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/139WUlo4dd3T2il-2zQ_-_X0v0xiJc7gB/view?usp=sharing)

```
 > df[1:100,1:6]
    AcousticTagCode      Species SiteCode         StartDetection           EndDetection Duration_min
1           5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-01 23:01:12.12 2014-10-01 23:59:41.41    58.488167
2           5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-02 00:00:06.06 2014-10-02 01:00:00.00    59.892167
3           5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-02 01:00:01.01 2014-10-02 01:20:12.12    20.185167
4           5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-02 04:14:15.15 2014-10-02 04:32:16.16    18.016833
5           5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-02 22:00:06.06 2014-10-02 22:59:54.54    59.791167
6           5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-02 23:00:10.10 2014-10-02 23:59:55.55    59.740667
7           5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 00:00:08.08 2014-10-03 00:59:46.46    59.639667
8           5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 01:00:10.10 2014-10-03 01:58:18.18    58.134667
9           5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 02:05:05.05 2014-10-03 02:36:11.11    31.101000
10          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 04:01:03.03 2014-10-03 04:43:35.35    42.538667
11          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 06:00:15.15 2014-10-03 06:48:23.23    48.134667
12          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 07:02:00.00 2014-10-03 07:57:33.33    55.555500
13          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 08:04:27.27 2014-10-03 08:59:19.19    54.865333
14          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 09:01:03.03 2014-10-03 09:59:36.36    58.555500
15          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 10:00:33.33 2014-10-03 10:58:50.50    58.286167
16          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 11:00:02.02 2014-10-03 11:59:56.56    59.892167
17          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 12:00:10.10 2014-10-03 12:18:01.01    17.848500
18          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 13:08:56.56 2014-10-03 13:24:06.06    15.175167
19          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 14:29:00.00 2014-10-03 14:58:52.52    29.865333
20          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 15:00:05.05 2014-10-03 15:59:17.17    59.202000
21          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 16:05:47.47 2014-10-03 16:59:50.50    54.050500
22          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 17:00:05.05 2014-10-03 17:43:37.37    43.538667
23          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 18:02:10.10 2014-10-03 18:38:58.58    36.791167
24          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 19:03:44.44 2014-10-03 19:58:26.26    54.697000
25          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 20:09:42.42 2014-10-03 20:58:24.24    48.697000
26          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 21:00:05.05 2014-10-03 21:59:03.03    58.966333
27          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 22:00:23.23 2014-10-03 22:59:46.46    59.387167
28          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-03 23:00:41.41 2014-10-03 23:59:29.29    58.798000
29          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 09:16:18.18 2014-10-04 09:59:35.35    43.286167
30          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 10:00:05.05 2014-10-04 10:59:18.18    59.218833
31          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 11:00:05.05 2014-10-04 11:59:59.59    59.892167
32          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 12:00:01.01 2014-10-04 12:59:49.49    59.808000
33          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 13:00:23.23 2014-10-04 13:42:25.25    42.033667
34          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 14:00:55.55 2014-10-04 14:53:26.26    52.528667
35          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 15:00:32.32 2014-10-04 15:24:24.24    23.865333
36          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 17:20:04.04 2014-10-04 17:24:09.09     4.084167
37          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 18:23:54.54 2014-10-04 18:52:30.30    28.612833
38          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 19:04:09.09 2014-10-04 19:59:58.58    55.808000
39          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 20:00:02.02 2014-10-04 20:59:56.56    59.892167
40          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 21:00:00.00 2014-10-04 21:59:59.59    59.976333
41          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 22:00:03.03 2014-10-04 22:59:57.57    59.892167
42          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 23:00:13.13 2014-10-04 23:59:57.57    59.723833
43          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 00:00:00.00 2014-10-05 00:59:43.43    59.723833
44          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 01:01:34.34 2014-10-05 01:59:58.58    58.387167
45          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 02:00:02.02 2014-10-05 02:57:00.00    56.959500
46          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 03:08:26.26 2014-10-05 03:58:33.33    50.117833
47          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 04:00:59.59 2014-10-05 04:58:36.36    57.629667
48          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 05:03:22.22 2014-10-05 05:54:09.09    50.781167
49          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 06:00:40.40 2014-10-05 06:57:54.54    57.218833
50          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 07:11:13.13 2014-10-05 07:59:52.52    48.639667
51          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 08:00:11.11 2014-10-05 08:59:55.55    59.723833
52          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 09:00:43.43 2014-10-05 09:59:52.52    59.134667
53          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 10:00:22.22 2014-10-05 10:56:15.15    55.882167
54          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 11:02:31.31 2014-10-05 11:53:29.29    50.966333
55          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 13:54:22.22 2014-10-05 13:59:12.12     4.831667
56          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 22:00:40.40 2014-10-05 22:59:59.59    59.303000
57          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-05 23:00:03.03 2014-10-05 23:59:37.37    59.572333
58          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 00:00:36.36 2014-10-06 00:59:19.19    58.713833
59          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 01:00:00.00 2014-10-06 01:59:54.54    59.892167
60          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 02:00:38.38 2014-10-06 02:59:46.46    59.134667
61          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 03:03:03.03 2014-10-06 03:59:16.16    56.218833
62          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 04:00:11.11 2014-10-06 04:36:28.28    36.286167
63          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 05:16:11.11 2014-10-06 05:58:33.33    42.370333
64          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 12:00:40.40 2014-10-06 12:58:17.17    57.612833
65          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 18:02:17.17 2014-10-06 18:12:23.23    10.101000
66          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 19:44:35.35 2014-10-06 19:58:00.00    13.410833
67          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 20:02:00.00 2014-10-06 20:59:59.59    57.976333
68          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 21:00:03.03 2014-10-06 21:43:15.15    43.202000
69          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 22:21:58.58 2014-10-06 22:59:49.49    37.865333
70          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-06 23:00:35.35 2014-10-06 23:57:08.08    56.545500
71          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 00:01:01.01 2014-10-07 00:59:19.19    58.303000
72          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 01:01:32.32 2014-10-07 01:53:55.55    52.370333
73          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 02:14:45.45 2014-10-07 02:59:33.33    44.798000
74          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 03:15:54.54 2014-10-07 03:59:57.57    44.050500
75          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 04:00:05.05 2014-10-07 04:31:31.31    31.437667
76          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 05:33:56.56 2014-10-07 05:59:16.16    25.343500
77          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 06:32:00.00 2014-10-07 06:43:00.00    11.006833
78          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 07:02:25.25 2014-10-07 07:29:22.22    26.949500
79          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 08:00:43.43 2014-10-07 08:51:26.26    50.713833
80          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 09:04:32.32 2014-10-07 09:46:55.55    42.370333
81          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 10:03:05.05 2014-10-07 10:32:47.47    29.707000
82          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 11:52:15.15 2014-10-07 11:59:56.56     7.673333
83          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 12:00:02.02 2014-10-07 12:42:19.19    42.286167
84          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 13:03:10.10 2014-10-07 13:59:59.59    56.808000
85          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 20:47:56.56 2014-10-07 20:50:00.00     2.074167
86          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 21:27:12.12 2014-10-07 21:59:08.08    31.932667
87          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 22:02:49.49 2014-10-07 22:59:16.16    56.444500
88          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-07 23:00:27.27 2014-10-07 23:58:00.00    57.545500
89          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-08 00:01:07.07 2014-10-08 01:00:00.00    58.882167
90          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-08 01:00:09.09 2014-10-08 01:59:57.57    59.791167
91          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-08 02:00:05.05 2014-10-08 02:59:03.03    58.966333
92          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-08 03:04:10.10 2014-10-08 03:55:12.12    51.033667
93          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-08 05:26:26.26 2014-10-08 05:59:28.28    33.033667
94          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-08 06:02:49.49 2014-10-08 06:59:58.58    57.134667
95          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-08 07:00:02.02 2014-10-08 07:59:40.40    59.639667
96          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-08 08:00:07.07 2014-10-08 08:59:50.50    59.723833
97          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-08 09:01:13.13 2014-10-08 09:51:35.35    50.370333
98          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-08 10:04:53.53 2014-10-08 10:59:09.09    54.276167
99          5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-08 11:06:27.27 2014-10-08 11:31:23.23    24.932667
100         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-08 20:03:30.30 2014-10-08 20:59:59.59    56.471333
```

1. A unique individual identifier "AcousticTagCode"
2. The individual's species "Species"
3. An observation site "SiteCode"
4. Start time for an event "StartDetection"
5. An End time for an event "EndDetection"
6. the duration of the event "Duration_min"

   ```
     AcousticTagCode      Species SiteCode         StartDetection           EndDetection Duration_min
   1         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-01 23:01:12.12 2014-10-01 23:59:41.41     58.48817
   2         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-02 00:00:06.06 2014-10-02 01:00:00.00     59.89217
   3         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-02 01:00:01.01 2014-10-02 01:20:12.12     20.18517
   4         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-02 04:14:15.15 2014-10-02 04:32:16.16     18.01683
   5         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-02 22:00:06.06 2014-10-02 22:59:54.54     59.79117
   6         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-02 23:00:10.10 2014-10-02 23:59:55.55     59.74067
   ```

There is an analysis done in a [recent paper](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0134002) where the authors use survival analysis to determine Continual Residence Time (CRT) at a site by defining an optimal time interval or Maximum Blanking Period* (MBP*) between consecutive detections at which it is probable that the individual is still residing at the site, but outside of the range of detection.

The basic outline is this:

Define the initial time interval for 1 mbp

```
mbp <- 7 #seconds
```

Create a list of integers to multiply by mbp to test survival analysis for different time intervals

```
n = c(1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512)
```

Here's where I'm stuck. For each value of n, I need to determine whether

```
n*mbp > StartDetection of Event[i+1] - EndDetection of Event[i]
```

If the above evaluation is True, I add the durations of all events until the event where the above evaluates False OR the `TagCode` changes OR the `SiteCode` changes.

for instance if `n=1` and `mbp = 7` in line 2 above, the time of `EndDetection` is `01:00:00.00` and the `StartDetection` time of the new event (line 3) is `01:00:01.01`.  The difference is `1.01` seconds which is less than `n*mbp`, therefore I would added the durations of lines 2 and 3 as a new variable `CRT`.  The problem is when more than 2 consecutive events all meet the above criteria as below:

```
   AcousticTagCode      Species SiteCode         StartDetection           EndDetection Duration_min
38         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 19:04:09.09 2014-10-04 19:59:58.58     55.80800
39         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 20:00:02.02 2014-10-04 20:59:56.56     59.89217
40         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 21:00:00.00 2014-10-04 21:59:59.59     59.97633
41         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 2014-10-04 22:00:03.03 2014-10-04 22:59:57.57     59.89217
```

here, the events from lines 38-41 all occur within 7 seconds of each other, the AcousticTagCode is identical, and SiteCode remains at RGD1 therefore the event durations all need to be added together and called `CRT`

Is there a way that I can take the initial data set here and create a new dataframe (df_n) for each iteration of n which has columns:

```
AcousticTagCode Species SiteCode CRT
```

using the two examples above this would look like lines 2 and n below:

```
head(df_1)
  AcousticTagCode      Species SiteCode    CRT
1         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1  58.49
2         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1  80.08
...
i         5004.24 Striped Bass     RGD1 235.57
```

Additionally anytime the condition is not met the event is considered a standalone event and CRT = Duration as seen in the above table line 1.

My skillset with R is fairly rudimentary, I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, but I'm not aware of it, and my searching skills have not availed me of anything remotely useful

Sample Data: [found here:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/139WUlo4dd3T2il-2zQ_-_X0v0xiJc7gB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please `dput()` a sample of your data. Thanks.

Comment: @kstew, I've provided a link to the full CSV at the bottom of the text.  I have now added the output from dput()

Comment: dput() was too large to place, I've placed in the first 100 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to do two things: 1) For each unique combination of acoustic, species, site code and start-end time, find all other matching acoustic-species-site cases where its start time is <= (mbp + end time of the original combination), then add duration to get CRT; 2) repeat this process for each value of mbp x n.

Since you haven't included any sample data, I have created some example data to try and match yours: 100 cases, where acoustic `a` can be 1 or 2, `species` can be 'bass' or 'trout', `site` can be 'p' or 'q', some random values, start times, and end times that randomly end 5-15 seconds after each start time.

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(a=sample(1:2,100,T),species=sample(c('bass','trout'),100,T),
                 site=sample(c('p','q'),100,T),
                 value=round(runif(100),2),
                 start=sample(seq(c(ISOdate(2000,1,1,0,0,0)), by = "sec", length.out = 100),100,F),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
df$end <- df$start + sample(c(5:15),length(df$start),T)
```

To accomplish number 1, I think you can take this approach: use `complete` to create the sequence of times within 7 seconds of each combination. Then use the possible sequences to join your original data. For example, if you have a row with `1-bass-p` and end time 00:00:21, possible matches are when other `1-bass-p` rows have a start time from 00:00:22 to 00:00:28.

```r
df1 <- df %>% arrange(a,species,site,end) %>% 
  distinct(a,species,site,start,end) %>% 
  mutate(end.orig = end) %>% 
  group_by(a,species,site,start,end,end.orig) %>% 
  complete(end=seq(from=end,to=(end+7),by='sec'))

df.orig <- df1 %>% select(-end.orig) %>% left_join(.,df) %>% filter(!is.na(value))

df.match <- df1 %>% ungroup %>% select(-start) %>% rename(start=end) %>% left_join(.,df) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value))

bind_rows(df.orig %>% ungroup %>% select(a,species,site,value,end.orig),
          df.match %>% ungroup %>% select(a,species,site,value,end.orig)) %>% 
  group_by(a,species,site,end.orig) %>% 
  summarise(crt=sum(value),n=n())

# A tibble: 97 x 6
# Groups:   a, species, site [8]
       a species site  end.orig              crt     n
   <int> <chr>   <chr> <dttm>              <dbl> <int>
 1     1 bass    p     2000-01-01 00:00:21  1.58     3
 2     1 bass    p     2000-01-01 00:00:26  1.38     4
 3     1 bass    p     2000-01-01 00:00:36  2.27     4
 4     1 bass    p     2000-01-01 00:00:42  1.69     3
 5     1 bass    p     2000-01-01 00:00:46  1.23     2
 6     1 bass    p     2000-01-01 00:00:55  0.84     1
 7     1 bass    p     2000-01-01 00:01:02  1.32     2
 8     1 bass    p     2000-01-01 00:01:18  0.74     2
 9     1 bass    p     2000-01-01 00:01:29  0.54     2
10     1 bass    p     2000-01-01 00:01:42  0.42     1
# ... with 87 more rows
```

To accomplish 2, you can use `lapply` to repeat this process over your values of mbp x n. This will return a list of 10 elements (i.e., length of n x mbp).

```r
mbp <- 7; n <- c(1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512) * mbp

f <- lapply(1:length(n), function(x){
  df1 <- df %>% arrange(a,species,site,end) %>% 
    distinct(a,species,site,start,end) %>% 
    mutate(end.orig = end) %>% 
    group_by(a,species,site,start,end,end.orig) %>% 
    complete(end=seq(from=end,to=(end + n[x]),by='sec')) ### x is here

  df.orig <- df1 %>% select(-end.orig) %>% left_join(.,df) %>% filter(!is.na(value))

  df.match <- df1 %>% ungroup %>% select(-start) %>% rename(start=end) %>% left_join(.,df) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(value))

  out <- bind_rows(df.orig %>% ungroup %>% select(a,species,site,value,end.orig),
            df.match %>% ungroup %>% select(a,species,site,value,end.orig)) %>% 
    group_by(a,species,site,end.orig) %>% 
    summarise(crt=sum(value),n=n())

  return(out)
})
```

Comment: I think that this works generally, but I've had a couple of  issues:
first 

1) I believe that, currently the code is double counting instances.  for line 1, there should only be a n=1, but n=2 and the value for duration is double what it should be.  2) if it is going to iterate through multiple n's and store it all in f, should there be a field in f where the iteration is defined?

I will add more data to help make this easier to check

Comment: I found an issue with my datetime formatting, I'm re-running with the correct POSIXct format

Comment: but now I get this error 12% of the way through:
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number

Comment: this error seams to be derived from an issue with POSIXct, apparently the program which created this file did not change times for PDT on March 09,2014.  Therefore a number of detections were recorded from 02:00 AM to 03:00 AM during a period in which POSIX believes no such date existed, therefore forcing an "NA" into the dataset.  Fixed by forcing all times to GMT, since absolute time is less important

Comment: Now this works beautifully.  I appreciate your assistance @kstew

Comment: I've run into a small issue using tidyverse to accomplish this task.  when n is large (>64) I'm running out of memory due to the size of table df1. I'm trying to remove the need to create a separate line for each second as is currently done in your code by using fuzzjoin to use inequalities to do the matching. Unfortunately, That seems to create an even larger table, which seems weird to me. code is below

Comment: `df.match <- df1 %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-start) %>% 
    rename(start=end.mbp) %>% 
    fuzzy_left_join(df1,df,
                    by = c("a"="a",
                           "species"="species",
                           "site"="site",
                           "end.orig"="start", 
                           "end.mbp"="start"), 
                    match_fun = list(`==`,`==`,`==`,`<=`,`>=`))%>% 
    filter(!is.na(value))`